# Error to open file in write mode

Tags: java, file-io, io

I tried to write a hexeditor as an exercise but I find my program always return error when try to open the file in write mode. Here is my program segment:

```
try {
    byte[] buffer={(byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xfe};

    out = openFileOutput(filename.toString(), 0);



    out.write(buffer, 0x50, 2);
    out.write(buffer, 0x5c, 2);
    out.write(buffer, 0x64, 2);
    out.write(buffer, 0x290, 2);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if (out != null) {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error code is returned from the failed open call?

Comment: Hi! You should post full stacktrace and source code of openFileOutput() method.

Comment: @suspectus Java API usually does not return error codes.